# Maximum number of comments from Youtube video with API?

Tags: java, youtube

What Java API code to use to retrieve more than 50 comments for selected video? Or this is impossible?
Thanks!

Comment: Can you use JSON data in Java?

Comment: If this will work - yes, i can, any technology on Java.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [the documentation](https://developers.google.com/youtube/2.0/reference), the maximum value for the max-results parameter is 50. However, it is possible to create a loop that reads 50 items per iteration using the [start-index](https://developers.google.com/youtube/2.0/reference#start-indexsp) parameter:

- http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/gzDS-Kfd5XQ/comments?v=2&alt=json&start-index=1&max-results=50&prettyprint=true
- http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/gzDS-Kfd5XQ/comments?v=2&alt=json&start-index=51&max-results=50&prettyprint=true
- http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/gzDS-Kfd5XQ/comments?v=2&alt=json&start-index=101&max-results=50&prettyprint=true
- ...

Notes:

1. The returned feed contains a property called `openSearch$totalResults` which gives you (approximate) number of total results. Or you can exit the loop when you get less than 50 results.
2. You can use `alt=rss` or `alt=atom` if you want data in XML format
3. `prettyprint=true` parameter is added for readability only

Answer (score 0):

From what I've researched, it seems the max amount of results (videos/comments) you can retrieve is 50, but it is not recommended. See [here](https://developers.google.com/youtube/2.0/reference?hl=it-IT#max-resultssp)