# Is there a limit on the number of comments to be extracted from Youtube?

Tags: java, youtube-api

I am trying to extract comments on some YouTubeVideos using the youtube-api with Java. Everything is going fine except the fact that I am not able to extract all the comments if the video has a large number of comments (it stops at somewhere in between 950 and 999). I am following a simple method of paging through the CommentFeed of the VideoEntry, getting comments on each page and then storing each comment in an ArrayList before writing them in an XML file. Here is my code for retrieving the comments

```
int commentCount = 0;
CommentFeed commentFeed = service.getFeed(new URL(commentUrl), CommentFeed.class);
do {
          //Gets each comment in the current feed and prints to the console
            for(CommentEntry comment : commentFeed.getEntries()) {
                    commentCount++;
                    System.out.println("Comment " + commentCount + " plain text content: " + comment.getPlainTextContent());
            }

           //Checks if there is a next page of comment feeds
            if (commentFeed.getNextLink() != null) {
                    commentFeed = service.getFeed(new URL(commentFeed.getNextLink().getHref()), CommentFeed.class);
            }
            else {
                commentFeed = null;
            }
        }
        while (commentFeed != null);
```

My question is: Is there some limit on the number of comments that I could extract or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: a little late but this link explains the limit cap that you mentioned : https://developers.google.com/youtube/2.0/reference?csw=1#Paging_through_Results

Answer (score 1):

use/refer this

```
String commentUrl = videoEntry.getComments().getFeedLink().getHref();

CommentFeed commentFeed = service.getFeed(new URL(commentUrl), CommentFeed.class);
for(CommentEntry comment : commentFeed.getEntries()) {
  System.out.println(comment.getPlainTextContent());
}
```

[source](https://developers.google.com/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_java)

Max number of results per iteration is 50 (it seems) as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10073690/maximum-number-of-comments-from-youtube-video-with-api)

and you can use start-index to retrieve multiple result sets as mentioned [here](https://developers.google.com/youtube/2.0/reference?hl=it-IT#max-resultssp)

Comment: I am using the exact same thing but the problem is that I am not able to go through all the comments on a video. For example, the video here [link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bizJWtJ0xXo) has more than 8,000 comments but I could get only around 980 comments.

Comment: what is the size of `commentFeed` ?

Comment: Each comment feed is of size 25 and it goes over max 40 feeds.

Comment: edited answer to address this max-cap on resultset also [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10073690/maximum-number-of-comments-from-youtube-video-with-api) helps

Comment: Ok here it is. The method `getNextLink()` (the one that I was using earlier) used to silently die before reaching `1000` but when I tried to use this more explicit method of max-cap and start-index, it throws an exception which reads like `You cannot request beyond item 1000.` So clearly there is a cap on the number of comments that I could retrieve. Is it related to the courtesy limits of Google APIs (although I did not come across such a thing earlier) or a more general limitation of the API itself?

Answer (score 0):

Google Search API and as well as Youtube Comments search limits max. 1000 results and u cant extract more than 1000 results